# Css: image to be always centered to the lines of text

Tags: html, css

I have an image and some lines of text next it. The count of lines is not constant. There may be one, two or three lines of text. Cases:

if only one line of text:

The image to be centered to the text

If two lines of text:

The image to be centered between the two lines

If three lines:

The image to be centered maybe to the middle line

Important note: I have very important requirement the container of the text should have specified height:

Here is my css so far:

```
.icon-several-lines {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.info {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     height: 120px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="icon-several-lines">
    <img class="image" src="http://lorempixum.com/25/25/abstract" alt="" />
    <span class="info">
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="icon-several-lines">
    <img class="image" src="http://lorempixum.com/25/25/abstract" alt="" />
    <span class="info">
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="icon-several-lines">
    <img class="image" src="http://lorempixum.com/25/25/abstract" alt="" />
    <span class="info">
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>

    </span>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bNsC/726/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use table layout, because that will allow to vertically align the content easily. With your current markup, you wouldn't need to change much.

```
img { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
.info { display: inline-table; vertical-align: middle; height: 120px; }
.info > p { display: table-row; vertical-align: middle; }
.info > p > span { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

**Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2bNsC/727/**

**Snippet:**

```css
.icon-several-lines {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
.info {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.info > p { display: table-row; vertical-align: middle;}
.info > p > span { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div class="icon-several-lines">
    <img class="image" src="http://lorempixum.com/25/25/abstract" alt="" />
    <span class="info">
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="icon-several-lines">
    <img class="image" src="http://lorempixum.com/25/25/abstract" alt="" />
    <span class="info">
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="icon-several-lines">
    <img class="image" src="http://lorempixum.com/25/25/abstract" alt="" />
    <span class="info">
     <p><span>test test test test test test</span></p>
     
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox (simple and effective way):

**CSS**

```
.icon-several-lines {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.info {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2bNsC/732/)**